# Basic Set Theory regarding the set $\{0\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

For each nonnegative integer $n$, let $U_n = \left \{n,−n\right \}$. Find $U_1,\:U_2,\:\text{and}\:U_0$.

$U_1 = \left \{1,−1\right \}, U_2=\left \{2,−2\right \}, U_0 = \left \{0,−0\right \} = \left \{0,0\right \} = \left \{0\right \}$

The first two sets make sense. Even the 3rd makes sense up until it becomes the zero set alone with one element. Can someone explain this or even better PROVE this?

$U_0 = \left \{0,−0\right \} = \left \{0,0\right \} = \left \{0\right \}$

Comment: $0 = -0$, and a set is made up of distinct elements (so as $U_0$ would have $0$ twice, it is only actually one element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point you're missing is that sets are only about membership; they have no concept of "repetition". Either a set contains $0$ or it doesn't; there is only those two options.

---

Here is a proof:

> $x \in \{ 0, 0 \}$ if and only if $x = 0$ or $x = 0$.

Therefore,

> $x \in \{ 0, 0 \}$ if and only if $x = 0$

Also,

> $x \in \{ 0 \}$ if and only if $x = 0$.

Thus,

> $x \in \{ 0 \}$ if and only if $x \in \{ 0, 0 \}$

and so we conclude

> $ \{ 0 \} = \{ 0, 0 \}$.

Comment: Thanks. I had the intuition. I mean I knew that sets are about "membership" I just didn't see it initially, but now I do. Thank you and thank you for the proof as well! Much more clear!